# Android studio android app not running

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android Programming.

I am using Android Studio for App Development. Till some hours back I was able to create and run applications but now something annoying has started happening.

This is independent of application so not providing any source code.

Problem : When I click on run app nothing happens.
Its seems as if it is not taking any action.

Output of Rebuild Project

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
:app:processDebugManifest
:app:processDebugResources
:app:generateDebugSources
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: C:\Users\Chetan\AndroidStudioProjects\MySongMixer\app\src\main\java\com\tgc\entertainment\mysongmixer\MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugAndroidTestDependencies
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl
:app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestResources
:app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources
:app:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestJava
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1 mins 7.729 secs
```

Comment: Any log anywhere whatsoever?...

Comment: In order to help others understand your issue, please post a sample of code, outputs of any logs (e.g. LogCat) or something to demonstrate a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem. At present, there is no possible way to determine what your issue is

Comment: What happens, when you click "Sync Project with Gradle Files"? Or "Build -> Rebuild Project"? There should be some output.

Comment: There is something wrong with android studio .. every application behaving the same way

Comment: @Jan then there is output

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes simply restarting your adb connection with adb kill-server the adb start-server commands will work.

I had a similar problem, which took longer to resolve, I updated Android studio, and my SDK - restarted and then it worked normally.

Hope this helps

Comment: Updating and restarting of no use

Comment: @user2653926 does this mean you have tried updating and restarting? what version of Java are you using?

Comment: Latest one.. Java 8 something

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is so vague I can't be sure that this will help but I would check your Run Configurations.

Make sure that package is set to "Deploy default APK"

Make sure that Activity is set to "Launch default Activity"

Make sure that Target Device is set to "Show chooser dialog" or the appropriate option for your runtime. Also, if you are using Emulator instead you should make sure that your emulator did not get corrupted and that it's properly set.

Comment: Tried running on physical devices as well as 2 different virtual ones

Comment: No Sir.. Its as if I have pressed nothing even though I clicked on run

Comment: I don't like being redundant but you did select "Show chooser dialog" without "Use same device..." when you clicked run, right? (I'm starting to run out of ideas here..)

Comment: @user2653926 I wasn't mocking you as stupid. I was merely noting that I didn't like that fact that I had to ask again because I wanted to make sure 100% at every step what is going on since I know that can be annoying so that I could better help you (think about any tech support phone call you had to ever do). People on this site are trying to help you, not insult you.

Comment: @user2653926 now, back to some professionalism. Have you tried reinstalling android studio? It might be a bug or some configuration file that went awry.